# Limiting Comments on Posts Index in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, associations, posts

I am new to rails and trying to limit the number of comments displayed on my Posts Index Page to 2.

Below is my posts_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.xml
  def index
    @posts = Post.all(:include => :comments, :order => "created_at DESC")
    @comments = Comment.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 1)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.xml
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.xml
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.xml
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.xml
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.xml
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(posts_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Below is my Post model

> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> has_attached_file :photo, :styles
>   => { :medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
>       :storage => :s3, 
>       :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
>       :path => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
>
> has_many :comments
>
> validates :name,  :presence => true 
>   validates :title, :presence => true,
>                     :length => { :minimum => 5 }
>
> end

Below is my posts index view

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>BoxScore</th>
   <th>Content</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= image_tag post.photo.url(:medium), :class =>"floatleft" %>
    <p>
  <%= post.content %>
    </p>
    <div class="comments center">
    <h3>Comments:</h3>
        <%= render :partial => post.comments.reverse %>
   <div class="links">
    <% if admin? %>
        <%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Comment on the Game', post %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Comments Partial Below

```
<% div_for comment do %>
    <p>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
        </strong>
                by
                <br/>
                <%= h(comment.commenter) %>
                <br/>
        <%= h(comment.body) %>
                <br/>
                <%= link_to 'More Comments', comment.post %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

I am not getting an error message, I just don't know how to limit the amount of comments we are rendering on Posts index page. Thanks

Comment: You should post the content of your partial too thats related to comments and say what kind of error are you getting with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify conditions on eager loaded associations, unfortunately. Likewise, you can't limit the number of rows returned based on a condition (to my knowledge, though there are a lot of things I don't know about SQL functions).

So you're stuck with either:

1. Load all of the comments for the posts you're displaying in a query, and limit the number shown in your application.
2. Load only 2 comments for each of the posts you're displaying *individually*.

The optimal solution depends on your use case. If you're expecting to show only 5 posts and have thousands of comments on each, option 1 might not be very performant and option 2 might be a good solution. If you are expecting to show more posts per page and have only a handful of comments on any one (the more likely scenario), the first option is going to be your best bet.

**Option 1**

```
# controller
@posts = Post.limit(20).all
@comments = Comment.find(@posts.collect &:id).group_by &:post_id

# view
<% @comments[@post.id].first(2).each do |comment| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**Option 2**

```
# controller
@posts = Post.limit(5).all

# view
<% post.comments.limit(2).each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: Calling `all` is usually a bad idea, if you do not want to ensure your result is an array. `ActiveRecord::Relation` responds to most of methods what `Array` have, so you can iterate with `each` or `map`/`collect` pairs. But `all` eager loads the resultset, what is not a good idea from performance's point of view.

Comment: @GaborGarami This *can* be true, but is certainly not always. If your application fits cleanly within Rails' CRUD, you can likely get away with letting your controllers assemble Arel queries that your view layer executes by iteration. There are many cases where this falls apart, though, such as when you need to manipulate data after retrieval, assemble custom cache keys, or modify those objects (e.g. `@post.touch(:last_viewed)`). It's also less that desirable to have your view triggering SQL queries (model's responsibility) directly, sans assistance from the controller.

Comment: Yeah, exceptions are always here :-). But at least in the answer's case, `all` is uneccessary.